# Is it possible assigning a key shortcut to a Command Alias in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio provides the option of running internal commands as specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-window?view=vs-2019) using a Command Console. It provides also the option of [assigning aliases to commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/visual-studio-command-aliases?view=vs-2019) (mostly to reduce the number of keystrokes). I found also [ConcatCommands](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChristianScheer.ConcatCommands) extension, which provides the option of concatenating the execution of more than one command. Now my interest focuses on assigning shorcuts to a command alias, but I haven't found a way of doing it yet, and I don't know if its even possible.

Does anyone in the room knows if its possible assigning a key shortcut to a Command alias in Visual Studio?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension. It supports executing a command alias, e.g. `DTE.ExecuteCommand("of");` for `File.OpenFile`, concatenating the execution of more than one command, and assigning a shortcut to a Visual Commander command.